# Laravel - Eloquent Models Relations, polymorphic or not?

Tags: laravel, model, polymorphism, eloquent

I have this schema
[image]

All the relations here must be one-to-zero/one.
A `user` can be either an `employee` or a `customer`. The `user_type` ENUM gives me the type so I know where to go from there.
Then an `employee` can be either `basic` or a `manager`. The `employee_type` discriminator let's me know that.

How am I supposed to build the Eloquent Model relations?

Let's say I have a user that is an employee. I need to get it's common fields from the `users` table but also need to get common fields from `employees` table. Do I need to hard code, and know that when `user_type=emp` I need to select from the `employees` table? What if I need to add another user type later?

**UPDATE**
Would it make sense to change my schema into something simpler?
My problem is that by using, as suggested, polymorphic relations I would end up to something like this:
$user = new User::userable()->employable()->...

**Would a schema in which I drop the employees table and have employee_managers and employee_basics linked straight to the users table?**

Comment: maybe all you need is just three tables, users, types, functions?

Comment: @mdamia I get the users table. The `types` table would hold something like 'customer, employee_manager, employee_basic'. What about `functions` table?

Comment: Funtions table is the combination of the other 3 tables.

Comment: Why do you need basics table? As far as I can see, details from basics table make sense for managers too, eg. position. Why not move these properties to employees table, and leave only managers?

Comment: I can do that. But then how would I build the Eloquent relatinships? Having only user, customer, employer and manager

Answer (score 0):

this is an polymorphic relationship. but if you want to be easy, you need to fix some things.

in the table employees

```
- user_id
- employable_id
- employable_type enum(Manager, Basic) # References to the target model
.... this last two are for the polymorphic relation, this is the nomenclature
```

in the basics and managers table you could delete the user_id field, but you need an id field as increments type

and now in the model Employee you need to make this function

```
public function employable(){
     return $this->morphTo();
}
```

I hope this works :)

Comment: But I guess I can do the same for users table. Have userable_id and userable_type and delete user_id for employees too. And this way i will have a users id, employees id and lets say managers id. These three ids will be different but represent the same user. Am I right?

Comment: in that case you must be change the employable function from morphTo to MorphMany because the FK is in the other table

Comment: I don't understand. Why MorphMany when my relations are one-to-zero/one?

Comment: Christian, because your your users/employees are linked to two entities/models simultaneously, that's polymorphic.

Comment: I understand why polymorphic. But now my question is how to make it happen in the models

Comment: just writing, $user->employees->employable.... and you'll get manager or basic data, its on the relationship